# ASP.Net Core Web App with Database publish to Azure with Visual Studio 2019 - Error with Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, publish

I have a problem when publishing my ASP.Net Core Web Application to Azure.
I nearly did exactly all the steps as in the tutorial here [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (multiple times). The only thing I did different than in the tutorial is, that I choose "Azure App Service -Windows" instead of "...Linux". I did it because when I choose the Linux option, later I was not able to see the publishing settings.

Now to my problem: when I want to set the options for the Entity Framework Migrations, there is an error that says that the .../project/config/dotnet-tools.json file is from another computer and is blocked due to security reasons.
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3YmN.png)
Can anyone help me here, please?

Thank you in advance!!!
Cini

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure whether the webapp has been successfully published before. If so, you can download the publish file from portal.

[image]

**Method one:**

If you have depolyed your webapp successfully before, you can get profile file from portal. Then you can import it in vs2019.

**Method two:**

If not, please delete `.vs` folder and `config/dotnet-tools.json` file, then rebuild your project. Make sure it works fine in local, then re-deploy it.

**Method three:**

[**optional**] I am sure that your vs2019 is not the latest version, please upgrade to the latest version to try.

**Method four:**

Re-create a new webapp (.Net 5), check if the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late response but finally I figured  out what the mistake(s) were.
I had the latest version of VS installed.

1. I had to choose Azure App Service -Windows because I use .Net 3.1.
2. My project was saved on One Drive, that was the reason for the error. As soon as I saved it on C: it worked.